# Camera Capture with External Camera with C#

Tags: c#, camera, aforge, emgucv

I have a Nikon D90 connected to my laptop via USB. I need to be able to simply trigger the camera to capture an image via C#.

This seems like it should be an easy problem but I have been drowning trying to figure it out...

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You would need [Nikon's SDK](https://sdk.nikonimaging.com/apply/) to accomplish that. What you're after is a remote control function for your camera. Nikon is offering their SDK for free but there's a lengthy T&C, a learning curve and a hunt for the C# wrapper so it's not a trivial task.

Comment: Thats helpful. Thanks. Can you help me understand what a C# wrapper is?

Comment: Wrapper serves as a bridge between C# and (in this case) Nikon's SDK enabling those who know C# to easily use the SDK without having to read tons of documentation and learn C/C++. Google for "nikon sdk c#" and you'll see what I mean.